# React Custom Drop-Down - remove click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, tabindex

I have made a custom **dropDown** with a div that I set an `onClick` attribute to open dropDown and close it. but also I want to **close** it when the user clicks to another part of the site.

```
 <div
    onClick={() => setIsDropDownOpen(!isDropDownOpen)}
    className="selected-drop-down"
 >
    <span className="dropDownText">{selectedQuoteCurrency}</span>
    <img
      className="dropDownIcon"
      src={require("../assets/image/arrow/dropDown-Arrow.png")}
      width="15px"
      alt="arrow"
    />
 </div>
```

I also do this logic

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(isDropDownOpen) {
      window.addEventListener('click',changeDD )
    }else {
      window.removeEventListener('click',changeDD )
    }
  },[isDropDownOpen])

  function changeDD() {
    setIsBaseDropDownOpen(false)
  }
```

But I was faced with a problem that when the component `didmount` for the first time everything is okay and dropDown opened and when click over there it closed, but for the second time, the dropdown didn't open because the state did not change to true.

furthermore, I tried to handle this click event by `tabindex` **attribute** according to this document => [developerMozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) but I didn't succeed

Comment: You shouldn't add and remove the event listener based on state changes. Add the listener when the component mounts, and do all required tests / commands inside the listener's callback. Also, this entire question hinges on the logic you used to implement this, but you're not showing us all the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover in css like this. when mouse go away from loc of dropdown menu, automatic close.

```css
.options:hover{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div className="options">
   <button>Add</button>
   <button>Logout</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: That is not at all what OP is asking about, and not a suitable solution to their problem either.